# regular expressions and a special character by itself

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace the character `&` with `and`, but only when `&` is by itself.  I try the following in **Python 2.7.3**:

```
import re
re.sub('&', 'and', '& r&b')
```

I get `and randb`, but what I want is `and r&b`.

```
re.sub('\b&\b', 'and', '& r&b')
```

Doesn't work either. Any suggestions?  Also, what's the expression if I just wanted a unique combination of normal characters and special characters, like if I want `a&b`, but not `a&bc`?

Couldn't find the answer in similar questions, so thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: Thanks, Marc.  The link doesn't address how to deal with special characters, but it was helpful for me to understand regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not knowing what "by itself" means. Btw, nobody knows what that means in regex.

Ror your specific example,

search `(^| )&( |$)`
replace `$1and$2`

Don't know Python though.

Edit: In Python

```
import re
re.sub('(^| )&( |$)', r'\1and\2', '& r&b')
```

Comment: This is exactly right. In python it would be re.sub('(^| )&( |$)', r'\1and\2', '& r&b').

Answer (score 1):

& is treated as a non word character. So just use this simple substitution.

Note: this will work for most usual cases in normal text.

```
>>> re.sub(r" & ", " and ", " & r&b")
' and r&b'
```

Comment: It works for almost all cases, but it matches, for instance, if you have & next to any other non-word character.  So yours passes for the string "&!"

Comment: Thanks for the observation. I am mystified why `\b` didn't work. Seems like there is a special case with `&`. Trying to understand that myself.

Comment: It seems that all that the \b checks for is that it is either beginning of line, end of line or that there is a transition from a nonword character to a word character.  So /b would work for a word character a-zA-Z0-9_ but not for a non-word character.  \B seems to treat inverse words.  I'm still struggling with this.

Comment: Please edit my post if required. I am answering from my phone right now.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for giving it a shot.